# How to model an interface implementation in UML that is dependent from a property?

Tags: generics, uml, class-diagram

I have a class `Properties` with two properties:
`kind`: Kind
`config`: Config

with `Kind` as enum type with some string in it.

What's contained in `Config` depends on the value of `kind`.

How can I model that in UML?

If I have, for instance, an `kind` value of "Service" the `config` interface will be implemented as `ServiceConfig`. Would it be enough to add a `constraint` annotation on the connector between `Config` and `ServiceConfig`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You model that with a constraint. This can be attached to either the class or the property itself. I can't write OCL but that would be the most formal way. However, a plain text enclosed in `{` braces `}` will do. See also https://www.uml-diagrams.org/constraint.html

---

RE your edit:

[image]

The `Config` interface is realized by two classes (bottom right). The constraint just tells what at runtime has to be done in order to instantiate `config`. Of course it's missing details like what shall happen if at runtime `kind` will dynamically change etc.

Comment: Great answer. For completeness sake, you could add multiplicities to both sides of the association.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Huu, you are asking something. I draw these for scratch always. I'll try to add it "somehow" ;-)

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Hmm. So I'm back. The OP does not tell where there should be multiplicities. I could guess a `1` near `Config`. But just guess. Did I overlook something?

Comment: OP mentions attribute `config : Config`. This is equivalent to an association with multiplicity `1` near `Config` and `*` near Properties. There might be an extra constraint in the context, not mentioned by OP, that would imply that multiplicity `*` should be something else, but as long as we don't have such a constraint, I would stick to `*` (or `0..*`).

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl What a coincidence. This one was still in my scratchpad.